# Use same method for all option menu in whole Application Android

Tags: android, onclick, android-optionsmenu

I have 10 to 12 `Activity`, All `Activity` has `Help Menu` as an `Option Menu`.
I am succeed with following code to create it and showing help on click of them.

```
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(cacheDir, "HELP.pdf")),"application/pdf");

    context.startActivity(intent);
```

But I want to Reduce this code for all Activity, and for that i have created one class and make one method but still i want to reduce code.

I have searched and found that `onClick` attribute is available in `OptionMenu` but I didn't get how to use it.

Please Help..

Comment: So you fire up a PDF document when pressing the options menu button?

Comment: Yes, Absolutely Right..

Comment: Make a super class of all activity and implement code into that

Comment: But there are some activity and fragment which is extending other classes.

Comment: Your other `Actiivites` would be extending `Activity` so you `extends Activity` in your super class and `extends BaseActviity` (or whatever you want to call it) in your other `Activities`

Comment: Its tough to me because i have used libraries and extends class of that library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created following Class for openFile:

```
public class OpenHelpFile {

    File cacheDir;
    Context context;

    /* Constructor */
    public OpenHelpFile(Context context) {
        this.context = context;

        if (android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))
            cacheDir = new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "OOPS");
        else
            cacheDir = context.getCacheDir();

        if (!cacheDir.exists())
            cacheDir.mkdirs();

        try {
            File helpFile = new File(cacheDir, "OOPS.pdf");

            if (!helpFile.exists()) {
                InputStream in = context.getAssets().open("OOPS.pdf");
                OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(helpFile);

                byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
                int len;
                while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
                    out.write(buf, 0, len);
                }
                in.close();
                out.close();

                Log.d(TAG, "File Copied...");
            }
            Log.d(TAG, "File exist...");

        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Log.d(TAG, ex.getMessage() + " in the specified directory.");
            System.exit(0);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void openHelpFile() {

        /* OPEN PDF File in Viewer */
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(cacheDir, "OOPS.pdf")), "application/pdf");

        context.startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

and I have call it from every `OptionMenu` like this:

```
new OpenHelpFile(context).openHelpFile();
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a class, for example call it `Helper`, where you put a method called `handleMenu(int id)` and where you do all the work. Then, in every activity you call that method from `onOptionsItemSelected()`, passing the id of the item selected.

Comment: What is need of `int id`

Comment: so you can know which item of the menu has been pressed, as defined in your xml menu file

Comment: ya.. In any Help Menu I have to call like following