# Cannot find path of file using Android PDF Viewer

Tags: java, android

I am using: https://github.com/jblough/Android-Pdf-Viewer-Library

```
intent.putExtra(MyPdfActivity.EXTRA_PDFFILENAME, "PATH TO PDF GOES HERE");
```

Where do I put my PDF files and what would the path to them then be?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20737477/1318946

Answer (score 0):

With a little search in Google and you would have found a question just like yours [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19817592/whats-the-path-in-jblough-android-pdf-viewer-library)!
Apparently the guy there have found a solution. Try it and see if it works for you. :)

Comment: I was actually reading that question a while ago... the answer does not seem to work for me and seems somewhat crude

Comment: Have you set the permissions? `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> `